# MacPro 2016 (macOS Sierra) keyboard delete button deletes whole sentence

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-sierra, mac-pro

MacPro 2016 (macOS Sierra) keyboard delete button deletes whole sentence.

I was cleaning the area around left arrow on my MacPro and now I realized that when I use delete button, it deletes the whole sentence (as if I press CMD+delete). When I was cleaning there was some weird windows popped up but I did not gave attention and closed them.

Does anyone know how to fix this situation?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that one of your two Command keys got stuck while you were cleaning your MacBook's keyboard.

To test this theory, try another keyboard shortcut that uses the Command key, without actually pressing Command, and see if the shortcut still gets activated.

For example, try clicking on Finder then pressing Shift+A (instead of *Command*+Shift+A) and see if it still opens Applications.

Comment: Thanks. I tested but Applications does not open without CMD.  Actually, I should add that that behavior does not repeat in every line but on some of the lines. It is not clear yet but I feel around the ones when I copy pasted some staffs. I am using R studio editor and writing a R Bookdown document. When I copy the lines in which I experience error to an Atom editor, deleting looks OK.